# Unable to see Jenkins Credentials values

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, jenkins-plugins

I'm trying to leverage the Jenkins credentials plugin to store sensitive data which I want to inject into Secrets within my Kubernetes cluster. I have a JenkinsFile which is used in my project to define the steps and I've added the following code to pull a username/password from a credential and pass to shell script to replace a placeholder in a file with the actual file:

```
stages {
    stage('Build') {
        steps {
           withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'creds-test', passwordVariable: 'PASSWORD', usernameVariable: 'USERNAME')]) {
               sh '''
                  echo $USERNAME
                  echo $PASSWORD

                  chmod +x secrets-replace.sh
                  ./secrets-replace.sh USERNAME_PLACEHOLDER $USERNAME
                  ./secrets-replace.sh PASSWORD_PLACEHOLDER $PASSWORD
                '''
              }
              echo 'Building...'
              sh './gradlew build --refresh-dependencies'
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

However whenever this runs all I ever get is the masked **** value back, even when I pass it to the shell script. Here is part of the build log:

[image: Jenkins Log]

Is there something I need to configure to get access to the unmasked value?

Comment: It is masked on purpose to not disclose secret for anyone who sees the log. If you really want to do this, write secret to file and then show file contents. `echo $PASSWORD > tmp && cat tmp`

Comment: I tried to do that too but even that outputs the **** value instead of raw text. The secrets-replace.sh script above uses sed command to replace the placeholder string with the credential value, but the latter is always ****.

Comment: What minas said is right, but misunderstood that it is _every_ bit of output which is filtered, so in order to "escape" it, you will need to mangle the secret text to no longer match what Jenkins thinks is a secret; my preferred way is base64 encoding: `echo "$PASSWORD" | base64` and then you can see what was actually echoed via `base64 --decode` on your workstation to recover the original text; you can do that with an entire file, too, if there is a secret file on Jenkins that you want to see what's up

Comment: Thanks, that seemed to do the trick! Much appreciated

Comment: Thank you @mdaniel. To store values in a variable `bucket_name_encoded=\`echo -n $BUCKET_NAME | base64\``

Comment: [This blog post](https://www.codurance.com/publications/2019/05/30/accessing-and-dumping-jenkins-credentials) by Andrzej Rehmann also lists several methods for revealing credentials in Jenkins.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Write the variable to a file in jenkins. Go to the jenkins workspace and look inside the file. The token will be present in plain text there.

UPDATE

Further easy way will be to print the `base64` encoded value of the credential and then decode it.

Answer (score 7):

Like the others added above, you could actually write it to a file and then cat the file outside of the withCredentials. You should be fine with this. As below..

```
withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'creds-test', passwordVariable: 'PASSWORD', usernameVariable: 'USERNAME')]) {
           sh '''
              echo $USERNAME > tmp
              echo $PASSWORD >> tmp
            '''
          }
          sh 'cat tmp'
```

This prints the actual credential values

Comment: Does not work - credentials are masked across steps

Comment: @jws, This works for sure. Ensure you are trying to print it outside the withCredentials block. Just tested this now again.

Comment: This works. Just remember to keep the cat command outside the Withcredentials section.

Answer (score 3):

Echoing straight from file didnt work for me so I tricked Jenkins like this to see the secret during debugging: Obviously, remove it right after debugging!

```
        stage('Build') {

            azureKeyVault(
            credentialID: 'my-sp', 
            keyVaultURL: 'https://my-kv.vault.azure.net', 
            secrets: [
                [envVariable: 'MY_SECRET', name: 'my-secret-name-in-azure-kv', secretType: 'Secret']
            ]
          ) {
                sh '''
                    echo -n $MY_SECRET | base64 > tmpp
                    cat tmpp
                '''
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider manipulating the string

`echo env.PASSWORD.toCharArray().join(' ');`

like

```
stages {
    stage('Build') {
        steps {
           withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'creds-test', passwordVariable: 'PASSWORD', usernameVariable: 'USERNAME')]) {
               script {
                  echo env.USERNAME.toCharArray().join(' ');
                  echo env.PASSWORD.toCharArray().join(' ');
               }
               sh '''
                  chmod +x secrets-replace.sh
                  ./secrets-replace.sh USERNAME_PLACEHOLDER $USERNAME
                  ./secrets-replace.sh PASSWORD_PLACEHOLDER $PASSWORD
                '''
              }
              echo 'Building...'
              sh './gradlew build --refresh-dependencies'
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How to see all secrets values in Script console:

```
import jenkins.*
import jenkins.model.* 
import hudson.*
import hudson.model.*
def jenkinsCredentials = com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.CredentialsProvider.lookupCredentials(
        com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.Credentials.class,
        Jenkins.instance,
        null,
        null
);
for (creds in jenkinsCredentials) {
  println("${creds.id} = ${creds.secret}")
}
```